# Jekyll can't find layout

Tags: github, jekyll

I am using git page to make a github website. I am using [academicpages/academicpages.github.io](http://academicpages/academicpages.github.io). I forked this repo to my gitpage repo, and edited the pages in the `/_pages` folder. But when I build the site with jekyll, I get the following:

```
  Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
 Build Warning: Layout 'single' requested in pages/about.md does not exist.
 Build Warning: Layout 'archive' requested in pages/dissertation.md does not exist.
 Build Warning: Layout 'archive' requested in pages/research.md does not exist.
 Build Warning: Layout 'archive' requested in pages/software does not exist.
 Build Warning: Layout 'archive' requested in pages/teaching.md does not exist.
```

I am not following this because, in the git repo I made I have the layouts in the `_layouts` folder. `archive.html` and `single.html` are all in there.

Then what could be causing the problem?

One question though would be, should I have all these files in the git website folder on my hard drive? Since I forked the theme repo, the files are all on my git repo, and I don't have the layout files on my hard drive.

Comment: Can you link your github repo?  It would make it easier to help you debug your issue if I can see the changes you made to the `/_pages` folder.

Comment: Please update the repo link. I guess you meant [academicpages/academicpages.github.io](https://github.com/academicpages/academicpages.github.io).

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation within https://github.com/academicpages/academicpages.github.io

> 1. To run locally (not on GitHub Pages, to serve on your own computer)
> 2. Clone the repository and made updates as detailed above
> 3. Make sure you have ruby-dev, bundler, and nodejs installed: sudo apt install ruby-dev ruby-bundler nodejs
> 4. Run bundle clean to clean up the directory (no need to run --force)
> 5. Run bundle install to install ruby dependencies. If you get errors, delete Gemfile.lock and try again.
> 6. Run bundle exec jekyll liveserve to generate the HTML and serve it from localhost:4000 the local server will automatically rebuild and refresh the pages on change.

So, yes, basically you clone the repo to have all files on your harddisk, then dependencies are installed and finally you start your site locally using `jekyll serve` or `jekyll serve -i`.